# NSFetchedResultsController: sort sectionNameKeyPath by day

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

If I have several fetched managed objects, with an attribute Date, how can I sort them in a table view by this attribute? If I set the sectionNameKeyPath to @"date", the section headers display titles like 2013-07-15 12:00:11 +0000. Of course, this makes sense, because I have not formatted them using any kind of NSDateFormatter, but even still, if I use a date formatter in

`- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`

There are duplicate days (because I have entities that have dates such as 7/13/13 1:00PM and another with 4PM the same day). How can I sort the fetched objects to display such that all objects with Date attributes for a given day are in their own section?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Group by day in NSDate with NSPredicate - needed to create multiple UITableView sections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942912/how-to-group-by-day-in-nsdate-with-nspredicate-needed-to-create-multiple-uitab)